# How to view imported certs in keystore imported by keytool?

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

I have imported certs into C:\ColdFusion10\jre\lib\security\cacerts keystore but how do I view them or verify that it's actually in the keystore? I have looked at a few documentations from Orcale but it's not showing how to view the list.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html                                                                                             Look at -list {-alias alias} {-storetype storetype} {-keystore keystore} [-storepass storepass] {-providerName provider_name} {-providerClass provider_class_name {-providerArg provider_arg}} {-v | -rfc} {-protected} {-Jjavaoption}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you prefer looking at the keystore with a nice UI, then take a look at http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There is also very nice GUI for keytool called [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Do I have to install this on the server that I imported the certs to or can I can install this on my local desktop and point to the server to look at the list of certs?

Second, when I tried to install this on my server, it gave me this message:

Keystore Explorer requires your Java Cryptography Strength be upgraded to unlimited.

If I do upgrade, will that cause issues on my web server? Currently this server is hosting a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can explore the KeyStore using Command Line or UI. I do it using the IBM KeyTool Utility which comes with the IBM WMQ Client.